# Is it possible to load a partial view in a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

can i create a webpage with a partial view which has another partial view inside?
I already tried but it ends all the time in an endless loop.
So just the question is this possible?

I add a image to show you what i want to do.
[image]
Thanks

Edit:
i load the Partial view like this:
parent:

```
<div id="ProfilPartial">
   @Html.Action("ProfilPartial", new { module = "1" })
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
<div id="ProfilPartialSelbst">
    @Html.Action("ProfilPartialSelbst", new { module = "1" })
</div>
```

He goes into both controller calls

Edit2:
Here are the Controller calls

```
[Authorize]
public PartialViewResult ProfilPartial(string module, int start = 0, int anzahl = 100)
{
    int benutzerId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    ViewBag.module = module;
    Benutzer user = Benutzer.AllList().Where(x => x.Id == benutzerId).First();
    if (module == "1") // Persönliche Daten
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilPersönlicheDaten", user);
    }
    else if (module == "2") // Unterschrift
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilUnterschrift", user);
    }
    else if (module == "3") // Rechnungs-Einstellungen
    {
        return PartialView("ProfileRechnungsEinstellungen", user);
    }

    else if (module == "4") // Angebote
    {
        return PartialView("ProfileAngebote", user);
    }

    else if (module == "5") // Leasing-Personaldaten
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilLeasingPersonalDaten", user);
    }

    else if (module == "6") // Status Selbstständigkeit
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilStatusSelbstständigkeit", user);
    }

    else if (module == "7") // Dokumente
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilDokumente", user);
    }

    else if (module == "8") // Passwort
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilPasswort", user);
    }
    return PartialView("RechnungMonatsUebersicht", user);
}


public PartialViewResult ProfilPartialSelbst(string module, int start = 0, int anzahl = 100)
{
    int benutzerId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    ViewBag.module = module;
    Benutzer user = Benutzer.AllList().Where(x => x.Id == benutzerId).First();
    if (module == "1") // Persönliche Daten
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilSelbstständigkeitWie", user);
    }
    else if (module == "2") // Unterschrift
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilSelbstständigkeitSchutz", user);
    }
    else if (module == "3") // Rechnungs-Einstellungen
    {
        return PartialView("ProfilSelbstständigkeitInfos", user);
    }
    return PartialView("RechnungMonatsUebersicht", user);
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to load the partial view

Comment: added to my question

Comment: I think I know what's happening - Please can you show your `ProfilPartial` and  `ProfilPartialSelbst` controller methods too

Comment: Okay, added to my question

Comment: hmm, can you try adding `@{
    Layout = null;
}` to your `RechnungMonatsUebersicht` partial view

Comment: wow that did it! :)
thank you, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
@{ Layout = null; }
```

to your partial view.

The problem is that rendering the partial view is calling your view **with** the layout.
Which in turn, is rendering the partial view. Which is rendering the layout. Which is... you get the idea, hence the loop (stack overflow exception

Another option would be to add

```
[ChildActionOnly]
```

to your controller methods

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult ProfilPartial
```

and

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult ProfilPartialSelbst
```